# shared, weak and lazy pointers in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, lazy-initialization, weak-ptr

Is anyone aware of an implementation of `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` together with a lazy initialization partner? The requirements of the classes were:

- A `lazy_ptr` class that allows a client to construct the object later (if at all), without needing the constructor implementation
- A `weak_lazy_ptr` class that has three possible states: not yet constructed (won't lock to a `shared_ptr`), constructed (will lock to a `shared_ptr`) and destroyed (won't lock to a `shared_ptr`)

I created some classes that didn't do the job completely a while ago ([see CVu article here](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/CVu222.pdf)) that used `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` in their implementation.  The main problems with a model that USES shared and weak pointers instead of integrating with them follow:

1. Once all `lazy_ptr` objects go out of scope, any weak references can no longer be locked, even if other clients are holding `shared_ptr` versions
2. Construction of objects on different threads can't be controlled

I'd appreciate any pointers to other attempts to reconcile these problems, or to any work in progress there may be in this area.

Comment: It almost sounds like `shared_ptr<boost::optional<T>>`, is that right?

Comment: @user1078210 Perhaps you can find more informations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878166/is-there-c-lazy-pointer).

Comment: @GMan: `boost::optional` *does* allow deferred construction, but `boost::shared_ptr` allows that too, so both are not needed, if I understand you.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Not quite. The difference is that when the optional is initialized, all the `shared_ptr`'s refer to the initialized object.

Comment: @GMan: That's right.  I didn't think of that scenario.

Comment: I have some work in this area in my private stash of code; will post it somewhere under boost license if I manage to dig it out.

Comment: @bronekk where could I view your code ?

Answer (score 2):

**To create deferred construction that requires no parameters:**

`boost::bind( boost::factory<T*>(), param1, param2 )` will create a function object that performs the equivalent of `new T(param1, param2)` without needing the parameters at the time of construction.

**To create a shared_ptr that supports this deferred construction:**

Bundle your factory with the standard `boost::shared_ptr` (in a class of your creation, for example), and you'llget the results you describe, including the appropriate `weak_ptr` functionality...

Whatever code triggers the **deferred construction** by the client should run:

```
your_shared_ptr.reset( your_factory() );
```

Whatever code triggers the object's **destruction** should run:

```
your_shared_ptr.reset();
```

The shared pointer will evauluate to `true` only during the object's lifetime.  And if you want you differentiate "not yet constructed" from "destroyed", you can set a bool after the factory is run.