# static variable initialization

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I have a template class that implements a singleton:

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
     static Singleton const& get() const { return _instance; }
   private:
      Singleton();
      static Singleton _instance;
};
```

There are some specializations of this template, for example, for `Type1` and `Type2`. And its constructors there are calls of `get()` of each other. I see a problem. Let's assume that `Singleton` of `Type1` is constructed at first:

```
Singleton<Type1>::Singleton() {
   Singletion<Type2>::get();
}
```

So the `Singleton` of `Type2` is not constructed yet. What will be returned by `get()`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `_instance` a `static` inside the `get` function.

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton {
     static Singleton const& get() const {
       static Singleton _instance;
       return _instance;
     }
   private:
      Singleton();
};
```

This way, the instance will be initialized the first time `get` is called.

Comment: yeah. Good idea. But what happens next? `Singleton<Type1>::Singleton()` calls the execution of `Singleton<Type2>::Singleton()` which need `static` `_instance` variable of `Singleton<Type1>` which is in construction.

Comment: @user14416 Probably undefined behavior. This is a circular dependency and surely a mistake.

Comment: Your idea does not fit me. I need these singleton initialization during the program start up.

Comment: @user14416 You should instead ask about what you're trying to achieve. Why do you need 2 singletons with circular dependencies?

Comment: Don't be so sure. I need to know what happens in my original question? Do you know?

Comment: That's an issue, they will invoke infinite recursion. Gcc would result in '__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error'

Comment: @user14416 in your original code you would be accessing something that didn't exist yet. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pubby you won't be accessing it: static initializers will deadlock, nothing will happen.

Comment: @user14416 See my answer for a deconstruction of your cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The cyclic dependency is bad:

```
struct Singleton2;

struct Singleton1 {
     static Singleton1 const& get() {
       static Singleton1 _instance;
       return _instance;
     }
   private:
      Singleton1();
      Singleton2 const& _s2;
};

struct Singleton2 {
     static Singleton2 const& get() {
       static Singleton2 _instance;
       return _instance;
     }
   private:
      Singleton2();
      Singleton1 const& _s1;
};

Singleton1::Singleton1() : _s2(Singleton2::get()) { }
Singleton2::Singleton2() : _s1(Singleton1::get()) { }

int main()
{
    auto& s1 = Singleton1::get();
    auto& s2 = Singleton2::get();
}
```

Will result in a failure (see http://liveworkspace.org/code/4rPFDo$0).

Like in all cases where you need to break cycles, make at least one link in the chain ***lazy***.

Solve it in the obvious way by not requiring a reference to the other singleton during construction:

```
struct Singleton2;

struct Singleton1 {
     static Singleton1 const& get() {
       static Singleton1 _instance;
       return _instance;
     }
   private:
      Singleton1() {}
      static Singleton2 const& getOther();
};

struct Singleton2 {
     static Singleton2 const& get() {
       static Singleton2 _instance;
       return _instance;
     }
   private:
      Singleton2() {}
      static Singleton1 const& getOther();
};

Singleton2 const& Singleton1::getOther() { return Singleton2::get(); }
Singleton1 const& Singleton2::getOther() { return Singleton1::get(); }

int main()
{
    auto& s1 = Singleton1::get();
    auto& s2 = Singleton2::get();
}
```

Alternatively delay-initialize using boost::optional, boost::flyweight or a custom 'lazy_ptr': https://stackoverflow.com/a/878298/85371